# Redirect to previous page after login in custom component

Tags: joomla-2.5, component, login, redirect

I want redirect users after login Current link in joomla 2.5 custom component I use this code but after login i have error 500

```
          $user =& JFactory::getUser();
          $mainframe  = JFactory::getApplication();
            if($user->id == 0){
                $uri =& JFactory::getURI();
                $url = base64_encode($uri->toString());
                $returnurl = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return='.base64_encode($url));        
                $mainframe->Redirect($returnurl,JText::_('Please Login'));
            }
```

how can do it?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$url = base64_encode(JUri::current());
$returnurl = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return='.$url, false); //false will make the URL non-xhtml
$mainframe->redirect($returnurl,JText::_('Please Login'));
```

Comment: thank I using your code but I have error 500 yet. when click login go to this link: index.php/component/users/?task=user.login and  have error 500

Comment: Try turning off SEF and see if it works. Do you have a 3rd party SEF extension installed?

Comment: when off SEF it's work but redirect to home page after login and do not use SEF extension only use default joomla

Comment: I enable SEF and Adds Suffix to URL now it's work but i want redirect after login to submitted menu but now redirect to user profile

Comment: You would need to do some debugging then. There's nothing wrong with the above code. Try outputting JUri::current(), $url, and $returnurl variables to make sure they're correct.

Comment: "i want redirect after login to submitted menu but now redirect to user profile" Sounds to me you're using JomSocial? JomSocial has their own redirection on login. You need to edit their system plugin, and also disable the jomsocialredirect plugin if you have it installed.

Comment: no i don't use JomSocial I using my custom component and created a menu from my component and when click this menu redirect to login and after login i want redirect to my menu